# Linux remote server: jstatd network unreachable

Tags: linux, rmi, jstatd

I'm trying to open a jstatd connection on my remote linux server, but whenever I try to run jstatd it gives me this error:

```
Could not bind /JStatRemoteHost to RMI Registry
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 2e6b:6d73:342e:6363:0:0:de04:6601; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
        at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.bind(Jstatd.java:57)
        at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:143)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 7 more
```

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy
```

I'm using java jdk 1.8_40 on my linux server:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

I've looked all over the internet but I couldn't find a solution to my problem, I hope someone is able to help me.

Kind regards, Daan.

Comment: How did you do in the meantime? Can you answer your question now, for those that run into it?